Excel VBA array prints nothing
I have declared an array as
Dim weights As Variant
The following program to print works:
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In weights
        Debug.Print item
    Next item

But the following program prints nothing:
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(weights) To UBound(weights)
        Debug.Print CStr(weights(i - 1))
    Next i

Please help.
I just noticed following works:
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(weights) To UBound(weights)
        Debug.Print weights(i, 1)
    Next i

Can someone please explain why?

how is weights declared - what is its content?

i starts at the lower bound of the array's dimensions, so using i - 1 as an index is not going to work. It also appears you have a 2D array ( probably populated from a range?)

weights = .Range("J2:J" & (nbonds + 1)).Value
this is how I populated weights

How to create a 1D array from a column?

Transpose the result. But why bother when you can just work with the 2D array?

You should declare array as
Dim weights() As Variant


A range returns a two-dimensional array where the first dimension represents the rows, the second the columns.
Try this code - adjust the way rg is set!!!
Sub printRange()
Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("J2:J" & (nbonds + 1)).Value

Dim weights As Variant
weights = rg.Value

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(weights,1) To UBound(weights, 1)
    Debug.Print weights(i, 1)
Next

End Sub

